# Generating previous 3 years and next months in array JS

Tags: javascript

I want to generate a list of years that should be dynamic. I want to show the current year, previous 3 years and next 4 years along with an empty object at the start. The output should be [2020, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2023, 2024, 2025, 2026, 2027]

I have a working function, but I'm wondering if there is a more efficient / preferment approach. It feels like too much code for a simple function.

```
const generateYears = () => {
  const previousYears = [...Array(4)].map(
    (a, b) => new Date().getFullYear() - b,
  );
  const futureYears = [...Array(5)].map((a, b) => new Date().getFullYear() + b);

  const years = new Set([...previousYears, ...futureYears].sort());

  const yearsObj = [...years].map((year: number) => {
    return {
      value: year.toString(),
      name: year.toString(),
    };
  });

  yearsObj.unshift({
    value: '',
    name: '',
  });

  return yearsObj;
};
```

Comment: Your current code does not generate anything for me. The bit with `Set` needs to be `Array.from(new Set([...previousYears, ...futureYears])).sort()`.

Comment: Your requested output contains the current year twice; is this intentional? It is not created by your code.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a `range` helper function for that. Something like:

```js
const range = (len, startWith = 0) => 
  [...Array(len + startWith).keys()].slice(startWith);
const getYears = (fromYear, nPrev, nNext) => 
  range( (nPrev + nNext + 1), fromYear - nPrev );

console.log(getYears(new Date().getFullYear(), 3, 4));
```

[See also](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-sfu85y?file=index.js)

Answer (score 1):

I will present a series of progressive refactorings, but here is the final code:

```
const range = (length: number, start = 0) =>
  Array.from({ length }, (_, index) => start + index);

const generateYears = (
  previousYearsCount: number,
  futureYearsCount: number,
  year = new Date().getFullYear()
) => {
  const years = range(
    previousYearsCount + futureYearsCount + 1,
    year - previousYearsCount
  );

  const yearObjects = [
    {
      value: "",
      name: "",
    },
    ...years.map((year) => ({
      value: year.toString(),
      name: year.toString(),
    })),
  ];

  return yearObjects;
};

generateYears(3, 4);
```

---

First, instead of creating multiple ranges, merging them, and deduplicating values, you can create a single range.
I would do this with a helper function, for clarity:

```
const range = (length: number, start = 0) =>
  Array.from({ length }, (_, index) => start + index)
```

This creates an array of length `length` containing a sequence of numbers starting at `start`.

With some other slight refactors (how the final array is constructed, etc.), that makes it something like this:

```
const generateYears = () => {
  const previousYearsCount = 3;
  const futureYearsCount = 4;

  const years = range(
    previousYearsCount + futureYearsCount + 1,
    new Date().getFullYear() - previousYearsCount
  )

  const yearObjects = [
    {
      value: '',
      name: '',
    },
    ...years.map((year) => ({
      value: year.toString(),
      name: year.toString(),
    }))
  ];

  return yearObjects;
};
```

---

To make this more reusable, you could allow the "center" year and number of previous and future years to be passed as parameters:

```
const generateYears = (
  year: number,
  previousYearsCount: number,
  futureYearsCount: number
) => {
  const years = range(
    previousYearsCount + futureYearsCount + 1,
    year - previousYearsCount
  );

  // ...
};

generateYears(new Date().getFullYear(), 3, 4);
```

---

If you mostly will use the current year as the "center", you could move that parameter to the end and make it optional:

```
const generateYears = (
  previousYearsCount: number,
  futureYearsCount: number,
  year = new Date().getFullYear()
) => {
  // ...
}

generateYears(3, 4); // Use the current year as the "center".
generateYears(3, 4, 2017);
```

---

Aside: If you want a more functional programming "feel", you could do it something like this:

```
const generateYears = (
  year: number,
  previousYearsCount: number,
  futureYearsCount: number
) => [
  {
    value: "",
    name: "",
  },

  ...range(
    previousYearsCount + futureYearsCount + 1,
    year - previousYearsCount
  ).map((year) => ({
    value: year.toString(),
    name: year.toString(),
  })),
];
```

---

(I arrived at this independently, but credit to @Kooilnc for getting there first.)

Answer (score 0):

Just made this is different way using ES6,

able to create the array as required in single line but adding the same was made manually,

```
let data=[{value: '',name: ''},...[...Array(7)].map((a, b) => new Date().getFullYear() + b-3).map((e)=>{ return {value: e, name: e }})];
console.log(data);
```

this is the exact format as shared in the example, modified as per the output of the question.

if it is all about array,

```
let data=[...Array(7)].map((a, b) => new Date().getFullYear() + b-3)
console.log(data);
```